# What are the reasons for the French opposition to opening a NATO bureau in Japan?

Tags: nato, france, japan

It has been reported in the news that France vetoed the opening up of a NATO bureau in Tokyo ([here](https://lanouvelletribune.info/2023/07/otan-un-differend-oppose-secretement-la-france-et-les-usa/), [here](https://lecourrier.vn/sommet-de-lotan-macron-confirme-son-opposition-a-la-creation-dun-bureau-de-liaison-au-japon/1184060.html), [here](https://www.japantimes.co.jp/news/2023/07/09/national/tokyo-nato-office/)).

But it is not clear what all of the aspects of this situation are.

Was there any official voting about opening this bureau? Or is it just France verbally expressing an opinion? If there is anything factual to that (a vote), does that mean there will be no NATO bureau in Japan in the near future? One of the articles says France gesture is "symbolic".

Comment: I'm not clear what exactly a NATO bureau in Japan would do.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Reading of articles that repeat Macron's opposition to the idea:

> Macron has been opposed to an increased NATO focus on China for years. In 2021 he said after a NATO meeting that “we shouldn’t confuse our goals,” arguing that “NATO is a military organization; the issue of our relationship with China isn’t just a military issue. NATO is an organization that concerns the North Atlantic, China has little to do with the North Atlantic.”
>
> NATO Secretary-General Jens Stoltenberg, on the other hand, has promoted deeper connections with Asia-Pacific allies. The leaders of Japan, South Korea, Australia and New Zealand will attend the NATO summit in Vilnius next week for the second year in a row.
>
> “We should not make the same mistake with China and other authoritarian regimes,” Stoltenberg said in February. His comment was seen as drawing a link between Ukraine and Taiwan. “What is happening in Europe today could happen in Asia tomorrow,” he said.

Japan themselves, according to the French, are not supposed to be very attached to the idea either.

It seems very much an idea suggested only by Stoltenberg, given his personal concerns above, one proposed in response to Japan's request for closer ties. France was also upset that the story broke before there had been a proper discussion and a vote, so this was very early stages indeed.

So, in light of a combination of an angry French reaction, China's reaction and Japan's distancing and it only being Stoltenberg's suggestion, the whole thing might very much just disappear.

Was there voting?

No, this leaked before it was formerly discussed.

Symbolic?

No, France is very upset and is the strongest voice of opposition.

Is a NATO bureau in Japan likely to materialize?

At this point, no.

Comment: To which can be added that France has a long history of occasional NATO-skepticism, frequently indicating a preference for a European-led military initiative, a tendency the UK usually countered.  Macron may not be the biggest proponent of that, and the "special military operation" has shown the real need for NATO.  But at the same time, the risk of getting Trump back in 2024 is also a reason for caution in relying too much on the US.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica Even if it's not verbally expressed (anymore), the idea that the US-led expansion of NATO to the former soviet eastern european countries triggered the russian invasion of Ukraine still lurks in the mind of many european politicians. Having been dragged into a near-war in Europe with Russia, and having to deal with the economical and social (refugees, mainly) repercussions of this war, they are very reluctant to any movement that could entangle the EU into a military conflict with China in the future.

Comment: @Rekesoft No need for propaganda. NATO didn't trigger Russia's invasion of Ukraine. Even using USSR definitions, Russia is engaged in a war of aggression. Russia lacks a casus belli for 2022 and 2014.